# private inner class implements an interface instead of parent, why?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I found a code, where there is an inner private class that implements an interface and returns value from it's enclosing class. is there any profit in making such thing, rather then implementing interface directly in enclosing class?

something like this:

```
public class Foo {
 public Whatever getWhatever() {  return new Boo(); }
 private Whatever boo;
 private int n;
 private class Boo implements Whatever {
  @Override int getN() { returns n; }
 }
}
```

maybe it's some sort of design pattern here or maybe there is some design pattern that looks similar to this?

Comment: If this private inner class is not reused anywhere else than in a single part of the top class, then is just pure code style.

Comment: Because one needs the method in the inner class. The same question would be, why one needs the inner class.

Comment: For that, exact use it seems pointless, but this is very much a question of context. Where did you see the code snippet? Is this code snippet exactly the same?

Answer (score 3):

One important reason is that a single instance of `Foo` can create and return many separate instances of `Boo`. If you imagine that `Foo` is a collection class, and `Boo` is an iterator; this will allow multiple concurrent iterations over the same collection, while keeping the implementation details of the collection private.

Answer (score 2):

It's often an API questions. Should "Foo" and "Whatever" really have an "is-a" (= inheritance) or an "has-a" (= composition) relationship.

It's good to design classes which do only a "single" thing (high cohesion).

Make sure you don't polute your API with implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

If the interface declares multiple methods, you can use that technique to avoid polluting the API of the parent class and instead provide a single method to get an instance of the private class. The class definition becomes more verbose, but I think reading and writing the client code becomes easier, at least if you use an IDE.

Depending on the context, there could be other uses.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same profit as with any interface. You will know the method exists within that class. If you are making several private classes and you want to be able to call specific methods on them, you can implement that interface.

If this is the only private class, it is not directly profitable. It is however always safe, since an interface requires your class to have implemented at least the skeleton of the method.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 2 patterns that are potentially used here:

1. Facade pattern - I have done things like this when wrapping or interacting with other external APIs and I don't want my code to get polluted with the external API interfaces.  This will allow my code to be ignorant of the external API and allow me to either change the implementation later or hide how ugly or confusing the external API is.
2. Factory method - by having a method create and return an instance, we can return different implementations of the interface or re-use already creating instances without taking up more memory.